# Why active voice is used in the sentence, not a passive?

Tags: meaning-in-context, passive-voice, active-voice

The example sentence is:

> The Views Framework is a core feature of Ambari and specific Views **build** on that Framework.

So why it is **build**, not **are built**? How meaning would changed if it had been **are built** instead?

Answer (score 3):

**"Build(s) upon"** tends to mean 'This thing uses that thing and *extends and improves* it's capabilities.'

On the other hand, **"is/are built upon"** just means that 'This thing uses that thing, but it doesn't necessarily improve it in any way'.

Comment: so if I understand you correcly, it should be __are built__, since Views doesn't improve Framework in any way?

Comment: Yes, that seems to make the most sense.